# node ffmpeg programmatically built list(?) of commands

Tags: javascript, node.js, ffmpeg, ffmpeg-wasm

I am working on a ffmpeg wasm project and I have it working with this code:

```
        await ffmpeg.run(
            '-loop', '1',
            '-framerate', '2',
            "-i", inputFileNames[0], 
            "-i", inputFileNames[1],
            "-i", inputFileNames[2],
            "-c:a", "libmp3lame", 
            "-b:a", "320k", 
            "-filter_complex", "concat=n=2:v=0:a=1",
            "-vcodec", "libx264", 
            "-bufsize", "3M", 
            "-filter:v", "scale=w=1920:h=1930,pad=ceil(iw/2)*2:ceil(ih/2)*2", 
            "-crf", "18", 
            "-pix_fmt", "yuv420p", 
            "-shortest", "", 
            "-tune", "stillimage", 
            "-t", "13", 
            outputFileName
        );
```

https://github.com/MartinBarker/ffmpeg-wasm-node

As you can see, the `await ffmpeg.run()` command takes a list of args / vars to run.
I have it statically set to take three file inputs right now (`-i`) but I need to have these inputs set dynamically for however many strings are inside the inputFileNames[] list.

I've tried giving `await ffmpeg.run(myListArgs)` a var containing a list of the same args but that does not work but this causes an error as it only runs the last var outputFIlename so this below does not work:

```
        let ffmpegArgs=('-loop', '1',
        '-framerate', '2',
        "-i", inputFileNames[0], 
        "-i", inputFileNames[1],
        "-i", inputFileNames[2],
        "-c:a", "libmp3lame", 
        "-b:a", "320k", 
        "-filter_complex", "concat=n=2:v=0:a=1",
        "-vcodec", "libx264", 
        "-bufsize", "3M", 
        "-filter:v", "scale=w=1920:h=1930,pad=ceil(iw/2)*2:ceil(ih/2)*2", 
        "-crf", "18", 
        "-pix_fmt", "yuv420p", 
        "-shortest", "", 
        "-tune", "stillimage", 
        "-t", "13", 
        outputFileName)

        await ffmpeg.run(
            ffmpegArgs
        );
```

I've tried to include multiple inputs in one line like so but it results in an error:

```
        await ffmpeg.run(
            '-loop', '1',
            '-framerate', '2',
            `-i ${inputFileNames[0]} -i ${inputFileNames[1]} -i ${inputFileNames[2]}`,
            "-c:a", "libmp3lame", 
            "-b:a", "320k", 
            "-filter_complex", "concat=n=2:v=0:a=1",
            "-vcodec", "libx264", 
            "-bufsize", "3M", 
            "-filter:v", "scale=w=1920:h=1930,pad=ceil(iw/2)*2:ceil(ih/2)*2", 
            "-crf", "18", 
            "-pix_fmt", "yuv420p", 
            "-shortest", "", 
            "-tune", "stillimage", 
            "-t", "13", 
            outputFileName
        );

[fferr] Unrecognized option 'i input-file-0 -i input-file-1 -i input-file-2'.
[fferr] Error splitting the argument list: Option not found
[ffout] FFMPEG_END
```

I've tried having only the inputs as a list, and using the ... to expand it inside the function call but that causes an error as well as the commas are included in the command (which they shouldnt be)

```
        let ffmpegInputs=[
            "-i", inputFileNames[0], 
            "-i", inputFileNames[1],
            "-i", inputFileNames[2]
        ]
        await ffmpeg.run(
            '-loop', '1',
            '-framerate', '2',
            [...ffmpegInputs],
            "-c:a", "libmp3lame", 
            "-b:a", "320k", 
            "-filter_complex", "concat=n=2:v=0:a=1",
            "-vcodec", "libx264", 
            "-bufsize", "3M", 
            "-filter:v", "scale=w=1920:h=1930,pad=ceil(iw/2)*2:ceil(ih/2)*2", 
            "-crf", "18", 
            "-pix_fmt", "yuv420p", 
            "-shortest", "", 
            "-tune", "stillimage", 
            "-t", "13", 
            outputFileName
        );

[info] run ffmpeg command: -loop 1 -framerate 2 -i,input-file-0,-i,input-file-1,-i,input-file-2 -c:a libmp3lame -b:a 320k -filter_complex concat=n=2:v=0:a=1 -vcodec libx264 -bufsize 3M -filter:v scale=w=1920:h=1930,pad=ceil(iw/2)*2:ceil(ih/2)*2 -crf 18 -pix_fmt yuv420p -shortest  -tune stillimage -t 13 cool-output-video.mp4
TypeError: a.charCodeAt is not a function
```

How can I create my ffmpeg args dynamically to work for any number of inputs?

Comment: I think what you are looking for is [Javascript spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fixed with syntax like so:

```
            '-framerate', '2',
            ...ffmpegInputs,
            "-c:a", "libmp3lame",
```